# How to display continuous bitmaps efficiently?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to display continuous bitmaps efficiently. First I tried with `SurfaceView` with code like the following:

```
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpNow, 0, 0, paint);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

However, the performance is bad and can not meet my needs. Then I tried it another way. I directly use `ImageView` and `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`, and this way performance was better than in the former case, but even so, it still can not meet my needs.

EDIT: *continuous bitmaps* are frames captured by a camera. They will display frame by frame with a UI widget like ImageView. I want this UI widget to display the frames fast and fluently, for example: display more than 15 or 20 frames per second. The problem is, I do not know which UI widget to choose, and how to use it efficiently.

Comment: Please be more specific, that do you mean by continuous bitmaps? What are your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fast frame-by-frame animation, you should consider using OpenGL. I suggest using either libgdx or andengine libraries.

Using the normal API will be easier, but there will be a lot of performance and memory issues that you will need to handle.

Comment: Just FYI; please don't ask people to accept/vote for your posts.

Comment: why not ? that's the purpose of the "V" button - it means you accept the answer as the best one that fits your question and answers it .

Comment: @AndrewBarber stop bugging people who ask for the most normal thing, there is absolutely nothing wrong about remidnign peopole of this option. read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers

Comment: @AndrewBarber You can not force your opinion about this, maby once you ask a question and someone remindes you of the option but thats it, if it wasnt a purpose of this platform to accep answers you wouldnt be rewarded for doing this or for providing the right answer (Accepted answer) STOP creating rules and get a life !

Comment: i never begged for any upvote . i only wrote that if that's the answer you see fit , you should accept it . that's of course after the person has written "thanks" . maybe new people (like this one) don't know of how it works . some people might also forget about having this feature . i myself also don't mark an answer till it really answers my question , but i also forgot to mark answers as answered or at least check them out again .

Comment: well i never had such a reminder , and i have a lot of unanswered questions and questions that i've posted and haven't accepted any answer (since i don't think they answer them) . every how many days do you get them ? maybe i've disabled it? is it on by default ?

Comment: can i somehow enable it ? sound like a very useful feature.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thats the issue, i ask questions and once i became the right answer i dont even think about accpting ijust go to my IDE, which is absolutely normal, hounestly politely reminding has nothing wrong about it, while describing this as begging is pretty insulting Anndrew, the fact that accepted answer get you the maximum reputation (15Pt) comparing to upvotes shows that this behaviour is beegin encouraged in this platform, and again i would fully agree that begging for votes is annoyeing, but reminding politly like "please consider accepting an asnwer" is ok in my eyes